# Powered rail on a slope powering glitch?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have placed a powered rail on a slope with a redstone torch underneath it as shown in the following two pictures.

[image: Redstone torch under rail]

[image: Powered rail unpowered]

Now as you can see, the powered rail is in fact unpowered, despite the redstone torch underneath it.

However, if I place a redstone torch next to the powered rail it is powered, but when I remove it, it continues to remain powered, as it should have done in the first place.

[image: Redstone torch next to powered rail]

[image: Powered rail powered without redstone torch]

Is this a glitch? Or some behaviour of redstone/minecart tracks that I am unaware of?

Comment: Try removing two blocks from the left side of the powered track so that the original torch can "breathe".  See if it exhibits the same behavior.  I know redstone torches have behaved strangely for me when I completely surround them.

Comment: Hmm I tried that but it doesn't appear to work. It doesn't appear to be a "breathing" problem here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a glitch relating to the updating of blocks.

In short, the issue is that when the powered rail is placed, it does not check to see if the block it is on is already powered, but keeps its state until a nearby block updates, such as might happen when you place a redstone torch that would power it.

When that redstone torch is removed again, the track checks to see if it still powered, and, realizing that it is, stays on. (c.f. the glitch that would give free power to tracks placed on a slope when one was removed from a chain of powered rails).

Anything that causes the track to be updated should make the track powered; such as placing the tracks sequentially from bottom to top, meaning that the initial state of the powered rail will be flat: When the next rail is then placed, pulling the end of the powered track up, it updates and gets power.

Another alternative, as Dan F mentioned, is to simply place the torch after the rail.

Comment: Ok, but this only appears to occur on slopes. Doing the same thing on flat ground (a redstone torch under the block the powered rail is on) powers the rail straight away.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Ta!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this counts as an *answer* per se, but I've had this happen to. Not all the time, just occasionally. I'm pretty sure I fixed it by digging down from the side and placing the torch under the block + rail, rather than placing the torch then placing the block + rail.

Comment: Yeah that works for me also. Any idea why it is necessary though?

Comment: @DanielL Nope, no idea. Completely threw me the first time it happened. Hopefully someone who knows what they're talking about will answer :-)

Comment: @DanF: Happy to help. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want this powered permanently, you could try using redstone blocks instead. I haven't tried this on a slope like this, but I typically power powered rails this way, in no small part because redstone is so plentiful.

Also, isn't this an example of a NOT gate?